# Change Nomad bind port

Tags: port, specifications, nomad

In HashiCorp Nomad, is it possible to specify the bind port for a Server and Client (e.g., from `464{6,7,8}` to `600{6,7.8}`?

The `addresses` stanza does not allow port specification, and neither does the `-bind` switch.
The `advertise` stanza does not change the port on which Nomad binds.

The `-bind` switch allows specifying IP only:

```
> nomad agent -server -data-dir=/tmp/nomad -bind=0.0.0.0
==> No configuration files loaded
==> Starting Nomad agent...
==> Nomad agent configuration:

       Advertise Addrs: HTTP: <HOSTIP>:4646; RPC: <HOSTIP>:4647; Serf: <HOSTIP>:4648
            Bind Addrs: HTTP: 0.0.0.0:4646; RPC: 0.0.0.0:4647; Serf: 0.0.0.0:4648
```

Attempting to specify a port errors out:

```
> nomad agent -server -data-dir=/tmp/nomad -bind=0.0.0.0:6000 
==> Failed to parse HTTP advertise address (, 0.0.0.0:6000, 4646, false): Error resolving bind address "0.0.0.0:6000": lookup 0.0.0.0:6000: no such host
```

Comment: May I point out that Nomad questions usually live on SO? Source: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=nomad

Comment: My comment above is in reference to the user that downvoted my question and my answer, who also pointed out that Nomad questions do not belong on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ports](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/configuration/index.html#ports) stanza to select ports for the agent, whether in server or client mode.

Answer (score 1):

you should look on hashicorp website how to launch nomad with **server.hcl client.hcl and nomad.hcl** file

:

```
echo 'server {
    enabled = true
    bootstrap_expect = 1
    
    }' > /etc/nomad.d/server.hcl
  
echo 'region     = "global"
    datacenter = "dc1"
    data_dir  = "/opt/nomad"
    bind_addr = "1.2.3.4" # the default

    advertise {
    # Defaults to the first private IP address.
    http = "1.2.3.4"
    rpc  = "1.2.3.4" #put your adresse here
    serf = "1.2.3.4:5648" # non-default ports may be specified
              }
    ' > /etc/nomad.d/nomad.hcl
```

and run this :

```
nomad agent -config /etc/nomad.d
```